# Fixing histogram drawn using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, axis

I need to fix my histogram by:

1. Setting the x coords vertically so that the text will be readable without pushing each other.
2. Removing the exponential notations.

Also I'm not getting why the vertical bars are detached from the x axis.

Currently the histogram looks like this

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis,
            height=6cm,
            width=\textwidth-1,
            ybar,
            ylabel={Secondi},
            symbolic x coords={
                    Creazione DID document,
                    Creazione chiave RSA,
                    Rilascio di credenziale,
                    Accesso al servizio,
                    Inoltro di richiesta,
                    Revoca di credenziale,
                    Creazione signature JWS,
                    Creazione Verifiable Credential,
                    Creazione Verifiable Presentation,
                    Resolve DID document,
                    Cifratura EAX,
                    Decifrazione EAX,
                    Handshake
                },
            nodes near coords,
            enlarge x limits=0.1,
        ]
        \addplot[] coordinates {
                (Creazione DID document,3.87)
                (Creazione chiave RSA,1.79)
                (Rilascio di credenziale,0.90)
                (Accesso al servizio,0.69)
                (Inoltro di richiesta,0.69)
                (Revoca di credenziale,0.83)
                (Creazione signature JWS,0.18)
                (Creazione Verifiable Credential,0.18)
                (Creazione Verifiable Presentation,0.22)
                (Resolve DID document,0.05)
                (Cifratura EAX,0.04)
                (Decifrazione EAX,0.04)
                (Handshake,0.31)
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Maybe are there better alternatives to what I'm trying to draw? I'm open to alternative recommendations.

UPDATE:

I rotated the histogram

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis,
            height=8cm,
            width=10cm,
            xbar,
            xlabel={Secondi},
            symbolic y coords={
                    Creazione DID document,
                    Creazione chiave RSA,
                    Rilascio di credenziale,
                    Accesso al servizio,
                    Inoltro di richiesta,
                    Revoca di credenziale,
                    Creazione signature JWS,
                    Creazione Verifiable Credential,
                    Creazione Verifiable Presentation,
                    Resolve DID document,
                    Cifratura EAX,
                    Decifrazione EAX,
                    Handshake
                },
            nodes near coords,
            enlarge y limits=0.1,
            % xticklabel style={rotate=90,yshift=0.2cm}
        ]
        \addplot[] coordinates {
                (3.87,Creazione DID document)
                (1.79,Creazione chiave RSA)
                (0.90,Rilascio di credenziale)
                (0.69,Accesso al servizio)
                (0.69,Inoltro di richiesta)
                (0.83,Revoca di credenziale)
                (0.18,Creazione signature JWS)
                (0.18,Creazione Verifiable Credential)
                (0.22,Creazione Verifiable Presentation)
                (0.05,Resolve DID document)
                (0.04,Cifratura EAX)
                (0.04,Decifrazione EAX)
                (0.31,Handshake)
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However some y coords are hidden and I'm unable to set the width to the \textwidth.

Here is the current result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
Now I see, that I didn't load correct version  of image as well diagram code (I test few versions). Also are corrected some spelling errors.

Like this?

[image]

You need to define:

- `nodes near coords style`, where you should add `/pgf/number format/fixed`
- `xticklabel style` where I suggest to define `text width`, that they can be write in two lines if necessary, reduce `linespread`, that size between `xtick` can be smaller and text appear at all of them
- appropriate define `ymin` and `ymay`
- appropriate set  `enlarge x limits` that all bars are visible
- appropriate set distance between `x` (meta) tick

Considering afore mentioned, MWE is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis,
            height=6cm,
            ybar,
            bar width=12pt,
            ylabel={Secondi},
            x=10mm,
            symbolic x coords={
                    Creazione DID document,
                    Creazione chiave RSA,
                    Rilascio di credenziale,
                    Accesso al servizio,
                    Inoltro di richiesta,
                    Revoca di credenziale,
                    Creazione signature JWS,
                    Creazione Verifiable Credential,
                    Creazione Verifiable Presentation,
                    Resolve DID document,
                    Cifratura EAX,
                    Decifrazione EAX,
                    Handshake
                },
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, rotate=90, anchor=west,
                                     /pgf/number format/fixed},              % <---
            ymin=0, ymax=4.5,                                                % <---
            enlarge x limits=0.05,                                           % <---
            xticklabel style = {text width=9em, align=flush right,
                                rotate=90, anchor=east,                                                                                                 
                                font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},    % <---
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
                (Creazione DID document,3.87)
                (Creazione chiave RSA,1.79)
                (Rilascio di credenziale,0.90)
                (Accesso al servizio,0.69)
                (Inoltro di richiesta,0.69)
                (Revoca di credenziale,0.83)
                (Creazione signature JWS,0.18)
                (Creazione Verifiable Credential,0.18)
                (Creazione Verifiable Presentation,0.22)
                (Resolve DID document,0.05)
                (Cifratura EAX,0.04)
                (Decifrazione EAX,0.04)
                (Handshake,0.31)
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you able to provide this plot by inverting the x and y coords like the one I added in my update?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro, now I see, that I didn't upload the last answer version. I will correct this ASAP. For your second sub question: please one problem per question. However, from given solution is no so hard to make "rotated" histogram.

Comment: however how can you set the width to be the exact \textwidth including the y labels? If you specify `width=\textwidth` for the xbar plot, the histogram will overflow

Comment: By trial and correcting errors? Due to defining  `x=1cm`, image width is 15cm (14 meta tick + 0.5 tick at start and at end of x-axis.  You need to prove, if I'm correct. BTW, you not provide MWE, so haven't any clue, about `\textwidth` in your document